# Why can't I change the height of my UITableView through code?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uitableview, height

I'm currently unable to change the height of my `UITableView` through code.

By default, it is set to `320` width and `289` height.

In the code, at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have...

`self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, [self.myPlayers count] * cell.frame.size.height);`

right before I return the cell.

I write out to NSLog and it has my width at `320` and height at `88` for 2 rows which is correct. However, my `UITableView` is clearly the same size as always (height `289`).

**What do I need to do to make this work?**

Thanks!

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is the method for the Cell not for the table.

Comment: when exactly you want to change the frame...?

Comment: if you cell height is dynamic you can count height in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. By use CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];. You better store calculated height to array and use it to calculate height for tableview

Comment: your table is in a UITableViewController or UIViewController? In a UITableViewController you can not change the frame...  because  self.view == self.tableView

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your height in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.
Probably something like this

```
[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 725, ([self.myArray count] * 44))]; //44 is default height for cell
```

You can also update this height in your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` if you are planning to delete cells and reduce your table height dynamically.

But make sure that you don't set tableview height more than the space you have for it because then the tableview will be cut

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the cell height at 44, how can I get the cell height in viewDidAppear. I know I can get the cell height viewDidAppear. Should I just check that there is at least 1 row in the table, and then pop the first off the stack?

Comment: Yes you can do it in `willDidAppear:`. And 44 is the default height for the TableViewCell, even in iOS7. So you need not worry about it

Answer (score 0):

The frame of the table view changes as table cells are added and deleted.if you are added more cell then the tableView height will increasing.

In your aspects 289 is a TableView frame height present cell display to user.

1 cell = 44; //default

So for you add two cell it size 88. so it will visible to user. In case your add 7 cell

7 cell = 308;

so your tableview size is increase based on total cell size and you try to scroll to view more cell

Answer (score 0):

You must set height in viewDidLoad. You need know how many rows you will print.

```
[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, ([self.Players count] * heightRow))];
```